# Make Run-Jetty-Run use the newest Jetty

Tags: eclipse, jetty, runjettyrun

I installed Run-Jetty-Run using the nightly site http://xzer.github.io/run-jetty-run-updatesite/nightly/, and I made sure to also install RunJettyRun Jetty93 Support:

[image: Run Jetty Run]

Despite that, when I right-click my project and click "Run Jetty", it starts an old version of Jetty:

```
Running Jetty 6.1.26
```

How to make Run Jetty Run use the newest version of Jetty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Click `Run` in the Eclipse menu
2. Select `Run Configurations...`
3. A window appear, find the `Jetty Webapp` item in the left pane
4. Create a new configuration if you don't have one already
5. In its `Jetty` tab, select the Jetty version you want, as seen below:

[image: Run Jetty Run configuration]